# Wordpress method to parse existing posts

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WP blog with over 7500 posts and would like to run a "batch script" on all such posts, to apply some changes to each post's content. For example filter some words or reduce the number of characters/images etc.

I'm familiar with PHP, but I'm not really familiar with Wordpress and the WP Codex. I know what I need to code once I get access to the actual post content, but getting there and after that saving the new content to WP DB is what I don't know how to achieve.

What is the best (straightforward & easy) option - running some batch script through PHPMyAdmin or is there some WP plugin that can be modified to achieve arbitrary operations on posts' content?

Does anyone have such a batch script in their workspace, willing to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it by testing, and again "thanks dude" to the one who downvoted the question without answering, just because.

So, the way to parse WP posts (just for visitor output, without altering in wpdb) is to go to "**/wp-includes/post-template.php**" and alter the internals of `the_content function`, ***before*** the `echo $content` statement. That's the most straightforward, yet unsafe way (if you don't know what you're really doing). Another safer way is to actually use the `apply_filter(the_content, 'your_filter')` filter hook if you know your WP stuff.

That's it, happy PHP-ing!